# eOS Loki - Video Tearing with Intel Graphic Card

Tags: release-loki, graphic-drivers, intel, videos

I am a happy loki user but the screen tearing in videos is horrible. It doesn't  matter if it is a video played in VLC or a YouTube or Netflix video in firefox. I always experience the tearing so it looks like v-snyc isn't enabled? I have an Asus K56CB Notebook with an integrated Intel Graphics card and an Nvidia 635M. The Nivida driver is installed through the app center but I use the intel chip because of battery life aspects. Besides, the nvidia chip doesn't a better job there.

Is there any change to get rid of that?

Comment: +1 - same here Acer Aspire V3-571G (Intel HD 2500 + nVidia 640M)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this solution,

Create a new file

```
sudo nano /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/20-intel_tearfree.conf
```

And paste this content inside,

```
Section "Device"
  Identifier  "Intel Graphics"
  Driver      "intel"
  Option      "TripleBuffer" "true"
  Option      "TearFree"     "true"
EndSection
```

Reboot, should fix your problem.

If it doesn't solve it / you don't want to keep the changes,
just remove the file by running

```
sudo rm /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/20-intel_tearfree.conf
```